# I can't set background image to specific div

Tags: html

Can anyone help me?

Here's the code

**CSS**

```
.booking-engine{
    min-width: 992px;  
    min-height: 150px;
    //background-color: aquamarine;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    background-image: url(images/taxi-img.jpeg) no-repeat;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div align="center" class="booking-engine" style="">

</div>
```

Comment: can you please post your html and a more detailed description of the problem?

Comment: Try putting a / in front of your url: /images/taxi-img.jpeg

Comment: have u check your div background image path is correct or not..in your browser element.?

Comment: `background:url(..) no-repeat`
OR
`background-image:url(..) ; background-repeat:no-repeat ;`
: you can't set no-repeat in background-image.

Comment: Double check the path - if your CSS is in an external .css file, then the path of the file is **relative to the position of the .css file** and *not* the position of the .html file that is linking to it.  (Edit: and as other's have said, get rid of the `no-repeat` and use `background-repeat` for it instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is an image path issue, also remove that `no-repeat` because `background-image` accepts only the `url()` value. If you want to use combined values then set the `background` attribute.

Comment: I'd also mention that the path use in an external .css file is relative to the location of the .css file... that could be part of it

Answer (score 0):

Hope it may help.

```
background-image: url(./images/taxi-img.jpeg);
```